# Filter a NSArray with another NSArray using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I would like to filter an `NSArray` with another `NSArray` using `NSPredicate`

```
NSArray *a = @[@{@"key1": @"foo", @"key2": @(53), @"key3": @(YES)},
               @{@"key1": @"bar", @"key2": @(12), @"key3": @(YES)},
               @{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];

NSArray *b = @[@{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];

NSArray *expectedResult = @[@{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];
```

I tried something like :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key1 like (key1 IN %@)", b];
NSArray *result = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But, unfortunately, I didn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple query. For getting the value of `key1` from array `b` you have to use simple `KVC` `valueForKey:` method.

```
NSArray *a = @[@{@"key1": @"foo", @"key2": @(53), @"key3": @(YES)},
               @{@"key1": @"bar", @"key2": @(12), @"key3": @(YES)},
               @{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];

NSArray *b = @[@{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];

NSArray *expectedResult = @[@{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key1 IN %@",[b valueForKey:@"key1"]];
NSArray *result = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Do this by apply intersection on `NSSet`

Here is the Example

```
NSArray *a = @[@{@"key1": @"foo", @"key2": @(53), @"key3": @(YES)},
               @{@"key1": @"bar", @"key2": @(12), @"key3": @(YES)},
               @{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];

NSArray *b = @[@{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];
NSMutableSet *aIntersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:a];
[aIntersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:b]];
NSArray *expectedResult = [aIntersection allObjects];
```

Comment: That answer is not satisfying because that kind of filter doesn't work by unique key testing. If `key2` was equal in to `@(94)` instead of `@(42)` for example it would not work... You can use the method `-[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInArray:]` instead of using `NSSet` to achieve what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by **NSPredicate** class method **+predicateWithBlock:**

```
NSArray *a = @[@{@"key1": @"foo", @"key2": @(53), @"key3": @(YES)},
                   @{@"key1": @"bar", @"key2": @(12), @"key3": @(YES)},
                   @{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];  
NSArray *b = @[@{@"key1": @"foobar", @"key2": @(42), @"key3": @(NO)}];   
NSArray *filteredArray = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [b containsObject:evaluatedObject];
    }]];
```